# how to handle If a subquery (inner query) returns a null value to the outer query

Tags: mysql, null, subquery

I have a vertical table like this:

| id | Profile_id | feature_id | value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | Rick |
| 2 | 1 | 2 | Novak |
| 3 | 5 | 3 | 5428 |
| 4 | 5 | 1 | Joe |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |

(above table is short part of profile_features table)

I have a query:

```
SELECT * FROM(SELECT `value` TelNum FROM `profile_features` WHERE `feature_id` IN (10, 64, 103) AND `profile_id` = 16752 LIMIT 1) as TelNum,
    (SELECT `value` NCode From `profile_features` WHERE `feature_id` IN (5, 61, 100) AND `profile_id` = 16752 LIMIT 1)  AS NCode,
    (SELECT `value` Fname From `profile_features` WHERE `feature_id` IN (1, 55, 86) AND `profile_id` = 16752 LIMIT 1) AS Fname,
    (SELECT `value` Lname From `profile_features` WHERE `feature_id` IN (2, 56, 95) AND `profile_id` = 16752 LIMIT 1) AS Lname
```

but if one of the subqueries returns null, query have not any output.

I want a row result with TelNum, NCode, Fname, Lname either they are Null or not null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use scalar subqueries in the select-list instead of your current Cartesian product:

```
SELECT (SELECT `value` FROM `profile_features` WHERE `feature_id` IN (10, 64, 103) AND `profile_id` = 16752 LIMIT 1) as TelNum,
  (SELECT `value` From `profile_features` WHERE `feature_id` IN (5, 61, 100) AND `profile_id` = 16752 LIMIT 1)  AS NCode,
  (SELECT `value` From `profile_features` WHERE `feature_id` IN (1, 55, 86) AND `profile_id` = 16752 LIMIT 1) AS Fname,
  (SELECT `value` From `profile_features` WHERE `feature_id` IN (2, 56, 95) AND `profile_id` = 16752 LIMIT 1) AS Lname;
```

Alternatively, you could learn to use LEFT OUTER JOIN:

```
SELECT TelNum.TelNum, NCode.NCode, Fname.Fname, Lname.Lname
FROM (SELECT NULL AS dummy) AS dummy
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT `value` TelNum FROM `profile_features` WHERE `feature_id` IN (10, 64, 103) AND `profile_id` = 16752 LIMIT 1) AS TelNum ON true
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT `value` NCode From `profile_features` WHERE `feature_id` IN (5, 61, 100) AND `profile_id` = 16752 LIMIT 1) AS NCode ON true
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT `value` Fname From `profile_features` WHERE `feature_id` IN (1, 55, 86) AND `profile_id` = 16752 LIMIT 1) AS Fname ON true
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT `value` Lname From `profile_features` WHERE `feature_id` IN (2, 56, 95) AND `profile_id` = 16752 LIMIT 1) AS Lname ON true;
```